# object tag html fallback loads even if flash player present

Tags: html, flash, fallback

What is the best way to prevent html5 fallback code from loading alongside the flash swf one?
I thought the fallback code only loads if flash player is not present, but it seems that it not only loads fallback html but it loads it first and in IE10 marks the swf file as pending (as seen in fiddler) until the ?fallback? iframe loads completely?
In this case it's a flash interactive animated banner with adobe edge html5 fallback loaded in iframe tag placed in fallback area of flash's object tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>ad_750x220_comm_noCTA</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        html, body { height:100%; background-color: #ffffff;}
        body { margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; }
        #flashContent { width:100%; height:100%; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="flashContent">
            <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="750" height="220" id="ad_750x220_comm_noCTA" align="top">
                <param name="movie" value="ad_750x220_comm_noCTA.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                <param name="play" value="true" />
                <param name="loop" value="true" />
                <param name="wmode" value="window" />
                <param name="scale" value="noscale" />
                <param name="menu" value="false" />
                <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                <param name="salign" value="" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="ad_750x220_comm_noCTA.swf" width="750" height="220">
                    <param name="movie" value="ad_750x220_comm_noCTA.swf" />
                    <param name="quality" value="high" />
                    <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                    <param name="play" value="true" />
                    <param name="loop" value="true" />
                    <param name="wmode" value="window" />
                    <param name="scale" value="noscale" />
                    <param name="menu" value="false" />
                    <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                    <param name="salign" value="" />
                    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <!--<![endif]-->
                    <iframe width="750" height="220" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="750x220.html"></iframe>
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                </object>
                <!--<![endif]-->
            </object>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

...now the iframe tags takes precedence in loading it's contents before the main swf file, even if flash player is installed.

Comment: Can you post or reference some sample code that demonstrates this effect?  A jsfiddle.com link perhaps?

Comment: You probably need to post some code or a link to an example to get help on this. I think your question is a bit vague as it is now.

Comment: I have updated the question with some sample code, please take a look.